# UIPickerView wont position outside of view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView that i positioned from Storyboard.
And i got this code to place it outside of the view bounds

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
[super awakeFromNib];
self.categoryPicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height, 320, 162);
}
```

but when i run the app the pickerView doesn't seems to move at all.

Any advice?
thanks

Comment: Can you please, print (just NSLog) self.view and self.categoryPicker?

Comment: yeah sure, right after these statements:

Comment: view - <UIView: 0x8e7c430; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e7ce50>>

Comment: picker - <UIPickerView: 0x8e7ba10; frame = (0 318; 320 162); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e748d0>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a bit of work any some good advice, the problem was solved.

The auto layout was turned-on, and once i turned it off could move the picker outside of the view's bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be that, your autoresizing mask is wrong. 
Try to set:

```
self.categoryPicker.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

and maybe:

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Comment: Tried that...didn't worked.. the problem is only in the loading of the picker, because after that when i hide the picker with the same statement it goes out of the self.view bounds...:/

Comment: I see your view is 480px height. Do you really launch the app in 3.5' screen?

Comment: I wanna lunch it all sizes..3.5 and retina. that is why i use the "self.view.bounds..."